# How do I get a free Minecraft cape without mods?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was wondering if there was a way to get a free Minecraft cape without mods or at least a mod that doesn't require forge. I don't mind if other people can or cannot see the cape, I just figured it would look cool. By the way, I don't mind if the cape is not custom either.

Answer (score 5):

To my knowledge only Mojang can distribute the "official capes", that all players can see. You can get them at [MineCon](https://minecraft.wiki/w/MineCon), or by making two mini-game maps, and uploading them to [Minecraft Realms](https://minecraft.net/en/realms/).

There are also "non-official" capes you can get through mods, that can only be seen by others who use that mod. [Optifine](https://optifine.net/home) has capes, but they are not free. There are, however, [mods available](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/2433855-minecraft-capes-mod-deadmau5-ears-upside-down?cookieTest=1) where capes are free.

Answer (score 5):

The only way to get a free Minecraft cape without using mods is to get one from Mojang itself.

Here is the list of methods how to get a cape from Mojang:

- Take part in an official Minecraft event: **Minecon**
- Temporary capes (given to everybody), example: 2011 New Year Cape, given to all Minecraft players on New Year's Eve
- Personal capes (example: Turtle Cape - given to 'billyK_' for suggesting to add turtles into the game)
- For translating the game to other languages
- For creating a Realms map
- Winning certain competitions in Scrolls or Cobalt
- Migrate to a Microsoft Account

Sadly, I did not find any mod that would enable you to have a free Minecraft cape without using Forge. However, if you really want that cape, then it may be worth it to use Forge to get one, or you can donate some money to OptiFine to get a cape (doesn't require Forge).

Answer (score 0):

For the majority of official capes, they are only distributed at the discretion of Mojang, mostly for attending events such as Minecon, or making a significant contribution to the game that Mojang has officially adopted, such as MrMessiah's better lighting cape, the Mojira Moderator cape or the Translator cape.

You can get a free official Cape with the migration from your Mojang account to a Microsoft account.

**How to get the Cape:**
All you need to do is migrate your old Mojang account to a Microsoft account and the Cape will be added to your account. The Cape can be seen by every Player once you equipped it.

To equip the cape once acquired, you have to log into Minecraft.net with your new Microsoft account credentials and at the bottom of the skin selection page will be the cape selection. Simply select the cape and press save.

Everything you need to know about migrating your account and getting a free Cape can be found [here](https://help.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/articles/4403181904525-How-to-Migrate-Your-Mojang-Account-to-a-Microsoft-Account).

[image: This is how the Cape looks]